# Why would a site completely drop out of Google Webmaster Tools Search Analytics chart?

Tags: google, google-search-console, impressions

[image: Analytics chart]

Do you guys have any idea why the main site for eg, say xyz.com would completely drop out of Google Webmaster Tools charts like this? I have never seen anything like this. It just looks like the site doesn't exist anymore on these charts but I know we're still getting hits. This is starting to make us a bit nervous.

Comment: One word. Panda. Panda 4.2 is out. However, there have been other updates recently too and there seems to be confusion abound. You are not alone. This sort of thing is happening all over. There is very little info specific to 4.2 except to point to 4.1. You can Bing these... (that's a joke).

Answer (score 1):

- Search `site:xyz.com` in Google.

Check if the your index links are
   still the same in numbers or not. Probably your index links are
   removed by Goolge.

- If not make sure your page rankings and backlinks are not ceased.

If you have recently added low quality external links to your sites
   remove it and crawl the pages again.

Comment: Yes index links are gone down from 400 to 130..wat can we do?

Comment: As I said check whether you have low quality backlinks of third-party sites or 404 errors or broken-links.
If everything is fine ask Google to re-index those pages manually using fetch as Google in Google Webmasters Tools.
`Dashboard > Crawl > Fetch as Google`
If my above answer helped you consider up-voting it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this scenario not so long ago, when without me knowing, redirect from HTTPS to HTTP URLs that we had for long accidentally got removed and 2/3 of our URLs got indexed with HTTPS instead of HTTP. And we had a HTTP version of the site registered with Google Search Console.
So, naturally, data was dropping on our property on GSC until I figured what the problem was and registered a HTTPS version of the site with Google Search Console, and started seeing our traffic on there...